# Loading parquet file from S3 to AWS RDS taking extremely long time using AWS Glue ETL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, etl, aws-glue

I am writing a Glue ETL script to read a parquet file from S3 (approx. 2GB) and uploading that to RDS. However, the runtime is over ~14 hours. Are there any solutions around this to make it faster?

I've read that custom JDBC drivers are super slow and certain transformations aren't able to be parallelised, but im not sure how accurate this is.

Here is a redacted sample code (NOTE: This script was created and edited using Glue studio):

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

import boto3
import re

# def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
#     for alias, frame in mapping.items():
#         frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
#     result = spark.sql(query)
#     return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node farmlands_raw.fact_inventory
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
result = s3_client.list_objects(
    Bucket="XXXX",
    Prefix=f"XXXX",
    Delimiter="/",
)
dates = []
for o in result.get("CommonPrefixes"):
    prefix = o.get("Prefix")
    dates.append(
        int(re.search(r"\d{8}", prefix).group())
    )
latest_date = max(dates)

print(latest_date)

node1661227531364 = (
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database="XXXX",
        table_name="XXXXX",
        push_down_predicate = f"upload_date = {latest_date}",
        transformation_ctx="XXXXX",
    )
)


# # Script generated for node SQL
# SqlQuery9 = """
# select * from fact_inventory limit 10
# """
# SQL_node1661227556612 = sparkSqlQuery(
#     glueContext,
#     query=SqlQuery9,
#     mapping={"fact_inventory": node1661227531364},
#     transformation_ctx="SQL_node1661227556612",
# )

# Script generated for node Apply Mapping
ApplyMapping_node1661227598286 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=node1661227531364,
    mappings=[
        .... redacted 
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node1661227598286",
)

# Script generated for node admin_ 579445444291_rds_connector
# admin_579445444291_rds_connector_node1661227607272 = (
#     glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
#         frame=ApplyMapping_node1661227598286,
#         connection_type="custom.jdbc",
#         connection_options={
#             "tableName": "fact_inventory_staging_temp",
#             "dbTable": "fact_inventory_staging_temp",
#             "connectionName": "qu_farmlands_raw_merged",
#         },
#         transformation_ctx="admin_579445444291_rds_connector_node1661227607272",
#     )
# )

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=ApplyMapping_node1661227598286,
        connection_type="custom.jdbc",
        connection_options={
            "tableName": "xxxx",
            "dbTable": "xxxx",
            "connectionName": "xxxx",
        },
        transformation_ctx="xxxx",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: What is the number of files you have in source and is it a single file? Have you tried creating Glue job with autogenerated code from legacy jobs page? If you are writing to RDS then why are you using custom JDBC driver? One optimization you can try is repartitioning your data after you read from s3 using repartition() in your current scenario.

Comment: In addition to @PrabhakarReddy comment, if you're writing to RDS, have you checked to ensure the bottleneck isn't in RDS?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the responses. Yes, it is only a single file. I am using a custom JBDC driver because the RDS is in another AWS account and I am unable to create a direct RDS connection in Glue. Good idea to check if the bottleneck is RDS. Will report back.  Cheers

Comment: repartitioning should fix it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this option in your dynamic frame creation :
`additional_options = {"useS3ListImplementation":True}`

Regards,